# How to use sublime text over SSH with multiple computers in same server using rsub?

Tags: ssh, sublimetext2, sublimetext3, sublimetext

We are using [rsub](https://github.com/henrikpersson/rsub) with multiple computers in the same server. However, every file we open gets directed to the same computer. How can we address this issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## LOCAL SETTINGS

In Sublime Text menu, go to `Preferences|Browse Packages`. Create a file called `rsub.sublime-settings` in the `Packages/User` directory:

**important**: use a different port for each machine that will be connecting to the same server.

--> Packages/User/rsub.sublime-settings

```
// rsub user settings

{
    /*
        rsub listen port.

        IMPORTANT: Use a different port for each machine.
    */
    "port": 52699,

    /*
        rsub listen host

        WARNING: it's NOT recommended to change this option,
        use SSH tunneling instead.
    */
    "host": "localhost"
}
```

Change your `.ssh/config` file:

--> ~/.ssh/config

```
Host example.com
    RemoteForward 52699 localhost:52699
```

## SERVER SETTINGS

Export the following variables in your `profile` (bash_profile, zshrc, etc.).

**important**: Make sure `RMATE_PORT` is the same that you used in your sublime settings.

```sh
export RMATE_HOST=localhost
export RMATE_PORT=52699
```

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your excellent instruction. I tried to add `Packages/User/rsub.sublime-settings` but Sublime Text 3 only shows the `Settings - Default` in the preferences menu so I guess it doesn't work well. Do you have any idea?

Comment: I put it in `Packages/rsub/rsub.sublime-settings` then the name of `Settings - Default` was not changed but it changed to my user settings inside. It works. Thanks!